# Auto Add Promo items for whole cart (with exclusions not working)

Tags: promotions

I am trying to create a free item promo [ i.e. Auto add promo items for the whole cart ] but with the following conditions applied:

Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met:

IF ANY of these conditions are TRUE

--IF ALL of these conditions are TRUE

```
 -- Payment Method IS NOT X (1)
```

--If product/item is FOUND in the cart with ANY of these conditions true:

```
 -- Manufacturer IS NOT X (2)
```

--IF ALL of these conditions are TRUE

```
 -- Subtotal equals or greater than X (3)
```

So what I am trying to do, is create a cart rule which excludes the payment methods set at condition (1), excludes ANY of the manufacturers selected at condition (2), and then adds a free product if the subtotal amount equals or is above the amount set at condition (3).

What I am finding is that the rule is correctly not adding the free item if any products from the excluded manufacturers list (2) are added to the cart, but even when products from the allowed list (i.e. everything else) and the total amount from allowed products exceeds the amount set in (3), Magento is not auto adding the promo item.

I've tried adding condition (3) above condition (2), here, the free promo item is correctly auto added when the threshold at (3) is met, but incorrectly allows items from the excluded list at (2) to count toward the subtotal.

Hope the above makes sense.

Any help would be greatfully appreciated.

[image: Cart Price Rule Conditionals]